# Efficient density function computation

Tags: python, opencv, optimization, numpy, scipy

I have a large image in numpy array form (opencv returns it as a 2d array of 3 uint8 values) and want to compute a sum of gaussian kernels for each pixel, i.e. (there's still no LaTeX support in SO is there?):
[image: density function]

for N different kernels with a specified weight w, mean and diagonal covariance matrix.

So basically I want a function `compute_densities(image, kernels) -> numpy array of floats`. What's the best way to do this efficiently in python? I'd be surprised if there wasn't already a library function in scipy for this, but I had statistics at uni a long time ago, so I do get a bit confused with the details of the documentation..

Basically I want the following, just way more efficient than naive python (2pi^{-3/2} is ignored since it's a constant factor that doesn't matter for me since I'm only interested in ratios between the probabilities)

```
def compute_probabilities(img, kernels):
    np.seterr(divide='ignore') # 1 / covariance logs an error otherwise
    result = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
    for row_pos, row_val in enumerate(img):
        for col_pos, val in enumerate(row_val):
            prob = 0.0
            for kernel in kernels:
                mean, covariance, weight = kernel
                val_sub_mu = np.array([val]).T - mean
                cov_inv = np.where(covariance != 0, 1 / covariance, 0)
                tmp = val_sub_mu.T.dot(cov_inv).dot(val_sub_mu)
                prob += weight / np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(covariance)) * \
                        math.exp(-0.5 * tmp)
            result[row_pos][col_pos] = prob
    np.seterr(divide='warn')
    return result
```

Input: `cv2.imread` on some jpg, which gives a 2d array (height x width) of a 3 uint8 struct containing the 3 color channels.

Kernels is a `namedtuple('Kernel', 'mean covariance weight')`, mean is a vector, covariance is a `3x3` matrix with everything but the diagonal being zero and weight is a float `0 < weight < 1`. For simplicity I only specify the diagonals and then convert it to a 3x3 matrix afterwards: (the representation isn't set in stone I don't care how it's represented so be free to change all of that):

```
some_kernels = [
   Kernel(np.array([(73.53, 29.94, 17.76)]), np.array([(765.40, 121.44, 112.80)]), 0.0294),
   ...
]

def fixup_kernels(kernels):
    new_kernels = []
    for kernel in kernels:
        cov = np.zeros((3, 3))
        for pos, c in enumerate(kernel.covariance[0]):
            cov[pos][pos] = c
        new_kernels.append(Kernel(kernel.mean.T, cov, kernel.weight))
    return new_kernels

 some_kernels = fixup_kernels(some_kernels)
 img = cv2.imread("something.jpg")
 result = compute_probabalities(img, some_kernels)
```

Comment: Check out scipy.ndimage (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html).  Build your kernels and then convolve them with the array using the convolve method.

Comment: Added a bounty in the hope that someone wants to provide an example on how exactly I'd use convolve and co to implement the function.

Comment: Voo, could you please add to your example some sample values and a sample call to compute_probabilities()? (and what it produces)  I will have a shot at doing this, but it is not entirely obvious what the types of the inputs are. I think covariance is a KxK array where K is img.shape[2], is that correct?

Comment: @Alex There we go, hope that makes it clearer

Comment: @Voo, please see answer below, I think it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, your goal is to evaluate the probability density of each image pixels value with respect to a mixture of multivariate normal distributions.

[There is currently (2013-11-20) a mistake in the code in your question and @Alex I's answer - the `| |` surrounding `\Sigma` in the above equation actually denotes the *determinant* rather than the vector norm - see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). In the case of a diagonal covariance the determinant is just the product of the diagonal elements.]

It is possible to implement the density calculation very efficiently
in terms of numpy array operations. The following implementation makes use of
the spherical (i.e. diagonal) nature of the covariance matrices in your problem:

```
def compute_probabilities_faster(img, kernels):
  means, covs, weights = map(np.dstack, zip(*kernels)) 
  pixels_as_rows = img.reshape((-1, 3, 1))
  responses = np.exp(-0.5 * ((pixels_as_rows - means) ** 2 / covs).sum(axis=1))
  factors = 1. / np.sqrt(covs.prod(axis=1) * ((2 * np.pi) ** 3))
  return np.sum(responses * factors * weights, axis=2).reshape(img.shape[:2])
```

This function operates directly on the kernels as they are initially 
represented, ie. *without* modification by your `fixup_kernels` function. When the normalisation factor `(2 * np.pi) ** 3` is removed (and calls to `linalg.norm` are replaced with `linalg.det`) this function matches the output of your code (well enough to satisfy `np.allclose`).

The closest out-of-the-box functionality in SciPy (as of 0.13) is the implementation of Kernel Density Estimation in scipy.stats (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde)) which defines a very similar
distribution where the covariance matrices are identical for each kernel - for this reason not appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Huh never seen `||` used for the determinant and for my small example choice the results were surprisingly similar enough to the correct solution that I didn't even notice, that alone should earn you the bounty ;) Great solution - I have to do more work with numpy, but reshaping and strides seem to be my best friends to solve lots of the non straight-forward situations efficiently and easily.

Answer (score 5):

*EDIT*

I verified that this produces same results as the original code:

```
def compute_probabilities_fast(img, kernels):
    np.seterr(divide='ignore')
    result = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
    for kernel in kernels:
        mean, covariance, weight = kernel
        cov_inv = np.where(covariance != 0, 1 / covariance, 0)
        mean = mean[:,0]
        img_sub_mu = img - mean
        img_tmp = np.sum( img_sub_mu.dot(cov_inv) * img_sub_mu, axis=2 )
        result += (weight / np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(covariance))) * np.exp(-0.5 * img_tmp)
    return result
```

Explanation:

`mean[:,0]` makes the shape simply (3,) instead of (3,1).

`img - mean` broadcasts to the whole image and subtracts the means from each pixel.

`img_sub_mu.dot(cov_inv)` is roughly equivalent to `val_sub_mu.T.dot(cov_inv)`.

`np.sum( ... * img_sub_mu, axis=2 )` is roughly equivalent to `.dot(val_sub_mu)`.  Can't use dot, though, because doing that will add extra dimensions. For example an array M x N x K dotted with an array M x K x N would produce result M x N x M x N, dot behaves differently on one-dimensional and multi-dimensional data.  So we just do an element-wise multiply and then sum along the last dimension.

Actually the "sum of gaussian kernels" bit in the question had me confused.  What is requested is a calculation in which, for each output pixel the value depends *only* on the input value for the same pixel, but not on the values of neighboring pixels.  So, this is nothing like a gaussian blur (which would use convolution), it is just a calculation performed on each pixel individually.

P.S. `1 / covariance` is problematic.  Are you sure you don't want `np.linalg.inv(covariance)` instead?

*OLD ANSWER*

It sounds like what you want is one of these:

[scipy.signal.convolve2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)

[scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html)

The question is a bit confusing, are you trying to calculate a bunch of images convolved with different gaussians, or a single image convolved with a sum of gaussians?  Is your kernel separable?  (If yes, use two convolutions Mx1 and 1xN instead of one MxN)   The scipy functions you'd use are the same in any case.

Also of course you'd want to pre-calculate your kernels with a combination of `numpy.random.normal` and `meshgrid`.

Comment: One image with several gaussians (on the order of a dozen and known at "compile time"). And ahem no idea if my kernel is separable, but I've added the naive python code for clarification.

Comment: Played around with convolve but don't see how I'd use it to implement the function.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get performance from Python is to not use Python.

There are many packages out there that work with Python syntax, but then use C or C++ backends. NumPy itself does this. Your problem appears to be tailor-made for something like [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) or [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/). Both those links show you how to use either system for kernels on NumPy vectors.

**Edit**: I'd love for one of my downvoters to let me know how I'm wrong. I'm suggesting a way to go if a pre-made function cannot be found. If you know of a way to do this with more performance than something like Cython or numexpr (i.e. a way to write C in Python syntax) then I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I'd think that some statistical package out there should already do this, I mean it seems like a not too uncommon thing. But yes if I have to I'd write it in cython, just seems like there should be already something around!

Comment: Maybe your opening line is all that's being read by the down-voters.

Comment: @Geoff you're probably right. I may need to find a more diplomatic way to say it. That statement is sadly true, though.